# Acces sql query for sorting non duplicate column among two other duplicate columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like

```
AccNo    cpno   Echeckid    EDescription

14D     150101  5004    A and N
14D     150101  5004    A and N
14F     191001  5019    Smart D L M
14F     191001  5019    Smart D L M
177A    011902  1016    P Bm and F
177A    011902  1014    B B - F/R
17D     011902  1016    P Bm and F
17D     011902  1014    B B - F/R
17D9    011901  1014    B B - F/R
17D9    011901  1016    P Bm and F
```

In the above table AccNo,cpno  `177A,011902 & 17D,011902 & 17D9,011901` combination has different Echeckid and EDescription. 
I'm trying to sort only AccNo,cpno combinations where Echeckid is different. Sorting table looks like .

```
 AccNo    cpno  Echeckid    EC Description
177A    011902  1016    P Bm and F
177A    011902  1014    B B - F/R
17D     011902  1016    P Bm and F
17D     011902  1014    B B - F/R
17D9    011901  1014    B B - F/R
17D9    011901  1016    P Bm and F
```

How do I specify that in access sql.

Comment: You mean sorting and filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the row by doing an aggregation and join:

```
select t.*
from t inner join
     (select accno, cpno
      from t
      group by accno, cpno
      having min(echeckid) <> max(echeckid)
     ) as ac
     on t.accno = ac.accno and t.cpno = ac.cpno
order by t.accno, t.cpno;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can start with:

```
select AccNo, cpno
from table
group by AccNo, cpno
having count(distinct Echeckid, EDescription) > 1
```

UPDATE:

if your version of access does not support distinct on multiple columns you can either concat them like `count(distinct CONCAT(Echeckid, EDescription))` or use `min <> max` as @GordonLinoff suggested

Comment: Does acces really allow `distinct Echeckid, EDescription`?Maybe `distinct CONCAT(Echeckid, EDescription)`

Comment: @Mihai probably you're right, I don't have access by hand, so if its not supported, you can concat columns to get single value

Comment: Access doesn't support `count(distinct)`.  Most databases don't support `count(distinct)` with multiple arguments.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd say most databases support distinct with multiple arguments, at least ansi sql 92 allows it

Comment: @Lashane . . . MySQL and Postgres (and hence Postgres derivatives) do, as does Hive.  SQL Server, Oracle, DB2/UDB, and Teradata are examples of databases that do not.